# php get html source code from https

Tags: php, curl, https, html-parsing

How to get html source code from https? I try to use `curl` instead of `get_file_contests`, but still not get the `image src`

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/simple_html_dom.php';

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.tumblr.com/');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

$html = file_get_html($query);
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
   echo $element->src.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: `file_get_html()` is not a function in php. itr may be [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: @diEcho file_get_html() comes from the simple_html_dom library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$html = file_get_html($query);
```

to:

```
$html = str_get_html($query);
```

The file_get_html function expects a file (or a URL), not a variable.